# oneOf at Swagger and YAML definitions

Tags: api, swagger, specifications

I am trying to create a REST contract using YAML and Swagger. So at this point a write all operations and now I am specifyng the contentes of service responses. 
        I need to make a choice between 2 objects. For this I am using (or trying) 'oneOf' as shown:

```
 ......
   responsavelPJType:
    type: object
    properties:
      dataInicio:
        type: string
      dataEncerramento:
        type: string
      tipoResponsavel:
        $ref: '#/definitions/tipoResponsavelType'

  tipoResponsavelType:
    type: object
    oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/pessoaFisicaType'
        - $ref: '#/definitions/pJType'

  pessoaFisicaType:
    type: object
    properties:
      cpf:
        type: integer

  pJType:
   type: object
   properties:
     cnpj:
       type: integer
 .....
```

The Swagger Editor gives me the Message: "***additionalProperty 'oneOf' exist in when not allowed***".

What is the correct way to use 'oneOf'?

Comment: See the linked question. You are using OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 which doesn't support `oneOf`. `oneOf` is supported in OpenAPI 3.0.